# servant a functional dependency error with `enter`

Tags: haskell, servant

I slightly changed the app shown in the servant tutorial to make `Reader` monad a `ReaderT`, like so

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators              #-}

module Lib
    ( runServer
    ) where

import           Control.Monad.Except
import           Control.Monad.Reader
import qualified Data.Text                as T
import           Network.Wai
import           Servant

type WebApi
  =    "static" :> Raw
  :<|> "foo" :> Get '[PlainText] T.Text

type Foo = String

server :: ServerT WebApi (ReaderT Foo (ExceptT ServantErr IO))
server = static :<|> foo
  where
    static :: Application
    static = undefined

    -- Handler T.Text
    foo :: ReaderT Foo (ExceptT ServantErr IO) T.Text
    foo = undefined

webAPI :: Proxy WebApi
webAPI = Proxy

readerToHandler :: Foo -> ReaderT Foo (ExceptT ServantErr IO) :~> ExceptT ServantErr IO
readerToHandler t = Nat (\x -> runReaderT x t)

-- readerServer :: ServerT WebApi (ExceptT ServantErr IO)
-- readerServer = enter (readerToHandler "foobarbaz") server

-- serve' :: Application
-- serve' = serve webAPI server

runServer :: IO ()
runServer = return ()
```

The trouble is I can't enable `readerServer` function, type checking fails with this inscrutable error

```
src/Lib.hs:45:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘ExceptT ServantErr IO’
        arising from a functional dependency between:
          constraint ‘Servant.Utils.Enter.Enter
                        (IO ResponseReceived)
                        (ReaderT Foo (ExceptT ServantErr IO) :~> ExceptT ServantErr IO)
                        (IO ResponseReceived)’
            arising from a use of ‘enter’
          instance ‘Servant.Utils.Enter.Enter (m a) (m :~> n) (n a)’
            at <no location info>
    • In the expression: enter (readerToHandler "foobarbaz") server
      In an equation for ‘readerServer’:
          readerServer = enter (readerToHandler "foobarbaz") server
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the presence of the `Raw` endpoint, which doesn't interact well with `enter`. This is a [known annoyance](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/157) in Servant.

The [`Enter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.9.1.1/docs/Servant-Utils-Enter.html#t:Enter) typeclass determines what sets of handlers can be transformed, and with what transformations. It has three instances:

- `Enter (m a) ((:~>) m n) (n a)` The simplest case. If you have a monadic action and a natural transformation that takes it to a different monad, you can apply the transformation.
- `Enter b arg ret => Enter (a -> b) arg (a -> ret)`. If you have a handler that takes a parameter and you know how to transform the final monadic action of the handler, you can transform the handler using the same `arg` transformation.
- `(Enter typ1 arg1 ret1, Enter typ2 arg2 ret2, (~) * arg1 arg2) => Enter ((:<|>) typ1 typ2) arg1 ((:<|>) ret1 ret2)` If you have a composition `:<|>` of handlers and each handler can be transformed individually using the *same* natural transformation `arg1`, then you can transform the composition with `arg1` as well.

This last condition fails in your example, because the handler for `Raw` has type `Application`, which is `Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived`, while the other handler is a `ReaderT Foo (ExceptT ServantErr IO)` action. The types don't match, so the composition doesn't have an `Enter` instance.

---

There is a [workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haskell-servant/jhDWkAZixuI/Hkm8CBAuEQAJ): call `enter` on your custom handlers, and only afterwards compose them with the `Application` handler.

```
type WebApi
  =    "static" :> Raw
  :<|> FooEndpoint

type FooEndpoint = "foo" :> Get '[PlainText] T.Text

readerServer :: ServerT WebApi (ExceptT ServantErr IO)
readerServer = static :<|> enter (readerToHandler "foobarbaz") foo
  where
    static :: Application
    static = undefined
    foo :: ReaderT Foo (ExceptT ServantErr IO) T.Text
    foo = undefined
```